# Small trees came back on one side only, are they affected by winter or disease?

Tags: trees

The two trees in the picture below seem to have been affected by either winter or the same disease
The redbud to the left lost its leaves on the exact same side last year during its first summer. That was due to an insufficient watering problem that I caused
The Japanese maple survived many winters but this year it came back as in the picture. Not sure what is going on Is this a disease or they are affected by winter

[image]

I also have two climbing roses that died back all the way to the ground. I have been struggling with these for years and I can't get them to grow and climb due to these diebacks

Can all these be due to mild winter that tricked the plants to still suck water from the soil and then a sudden temp drop affected them

Answer (score 1):

The location would help . Redbuds are cold hardy to zone 5. Here in zone 8 redbuds are prolific and naturally grow in forest areas. The only problem with red buds is heart rot, common here. It kills trees a section at a time over a few years, I suspect that has killed part of your tree. I know of no treatment. There are redbuds in my yard ; as one dies of heart rot , I let volunteers come up nearby. The saplings need to be protected from deer. Roses (tea) are very cold hardy, so that is unlikely a problem.

Comment: I am in Toronto. This is a cultivar the Gold hearts variety. What should I do with it ?

Comment: That is pretty far north for redbud  so maybe is is a cold problem.